# Как удалить или поменять строку из ArrayList?

Tags: java

Есть лист строк:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Как удалить строку, например с номером 5?
Как поменять значение этой строки?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Удалить:

```
list.remove(5);
```

Поменять значение:

```
list.set(5, "new value");
```

Comment: этот вариант вернет `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: @DimaKhodan, В данном конкретном случае никаких экзепшенов не будет.

Comment: Номер != индекс. Измените на 4 :D

Comment: @post_zeew ну это если использовать только или первый или второй метод отдельно. если же сделать ремув, а потом апдейт то он таки вылетит.

Answer (score 1):

1) Строки неизменяемые`(immutable)`. 
Вы не можете изменить строку в 5м индексе, но можете записать туда новую. Это очень важный момент в джаве и об это стоит помнить. Если только это не `StringBuilder` или `StringBuffer`.

2) Для изменения размеров `List` используйте `Iterator` или в обратном случае вы получите `ConcurrentModificationException`.

3) 
`list.iterate();
 iterator.remove(i);
 list.set(i, "string")`

Comment: Спасибо. Учту это.